# How can an external package implement an interface implicitly?

Tags: go, interface

I'm writing a piece of code that relies on some implementation.
I want to decouple the implementation from my code, and make the implementation as independent as possible.
I thought of achieving this approach by using interfaces instead of concrete types, like so:

```golang
package mypackage

type MyType interface {
    Title() string
    Price() int
}

type TypeGetter interface {
    GetType() MyType
}

func MyHandler(tg TypeGetter) {
    t := tg.GetType()
    fmt.Printf("Title: %s, Price: %d", t.Title(), t.Price())
}
```

And an implementation might be something like this:

```golang
package external

// CustomType implicitly implements the MyType interface
type CustomType struct {
    title string
    price int
}
func (t CustomType) Title() string { return t.title }
func (t CustomType) Price() int { return t.price }


// CustomTypeGetter implicitly implements the TypeGetter interface. Or is it???
type CustomTypeGetter struct {
}
func (g CustomTypeGetter) GetType() CustomType {
    return CustomType{"Hello", 42}
}
```

Then, the code would do something like this:

```golang
package main

import "mypackage"
import "external"

func main() {
    tg := external.CustomTypeGetter{}
    mypackage.MyHandler(tg)            // <--- the compiler does not like this
}
```

I hope the example speaks for itself: I have no coupling between "mypackage" and the "external" package, which may be replaced, substituted my mocks for testing, etc.

The problem: the compiler complains that the call to `MyHandler` has an object that implements:
`func GetType() CustomType`, instead of:
`func GetType() MyType`

The only solution I found is to move the interface declarations (`MyType` and `TypeGetter`) to a *third* package, and then both "mypackage" and "external" packages can use it.
But I want to avoid that.

Isn't Go's concept of *implicit* implementation of interfaces contradict the idea of a third *common* package?

Is there a way to implement such thing, without *binding* the two packages together?

Comment: `I have no coupling between "mypackage" and the "external" package, which may be replaced, substituted my mocks for testing, etc.` There is always a kind of coupling otherwise you would not be able to use one within the other, even if it hidden behind some implicitness thing. see for yourself https://go.dev/play/p/QVNmQLiEgdh

Comment: Of course there is always a "kind" of coupling. But there's a difference between requiring the _implementation_ to use code from the client side or not. Imagine that in order to implement the `Reader` interface you'd need to `import os`....

Answer (score 1):

> Isn't Go's concept of implicit implementation of interfaces contradict the idea of a third common package?

I think it does. Go authors introduced an implicit interface implementation to eliminate unnecessary dependencies between packages. That works well for simple interfaces like `io.Reader`, but you cannot apply it everywhere.

One of the language creators, [Rob Pike, says](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PAAkCSZUG1c&t=317s) that the non-declarative satisfaction of interfaces is not the essential part of the idea behind interfaces in Go. It's a nice feature, but not all elements of the language are practical or possible to use every time.

For complex interfaces, you need to import a package where the interface is defined. For example, if you want to implement an SQL driver that works with the `sql` package from the standard library, you must import the [`sql/driver`](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql/driver#Driver) package.

I would recommend not introducing interfaces at the beginning of your project. Usually, it leads to situations where you need to solve artificial problems like rewriting the interface each time you updates your understanding of the domain model. It is hard to come up with a good abstraction from the first attempt, and, in many cases, it is unnecessary, in my opinion.

> I need to query external source for products. I don't care how the external sources store the data (db, file, network). I just need a "product" type. So it's either I define a Product type, forcing the external implementations to import and use it, or the Go way - define a Product interface and let the implementations implicitly implement this interface. Which apparently doesn't work

I see two loosely related goals here:

1. Define an interface to swap implementations of the product source.
2. A package that implements the product source should not import the package that defines the interface.

From my experience, I would recommend doing point 1 only when you have at least one working implementation of the product source service.

Point 2 is not always possible to achieve, and it is fine; please see the example from the standard Go library above.

P.S.
Please, consider not creating `Product` interface. While it does makes sense to come up with the `PorductSource` interface eventually, `Product` is most probably just a set of data; `struct` is a perfect way to represent such information. Please, see [this very relevant code smaple](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/golang-samples/blob/aeec04e7233c1119384356dcbbf04c35bbde10fe/getting-started/bookshelf/book.go#L34-L58) and [this article](https://commandercoriander.net/blog/2018/03/30/go-interfaces/) for inspiration.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The goal is simple: I need to query external source for products. I don't care how the external sources store the data (db, file, network). I just need a "product" type. So it's either I define a `Product` type, forcing the external implementations to import and use it; or the Go way - define a `Product` _interface_ and let the implementations _implicitly_ implement this interface. Which apparently doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your approach is that you want someone to implement an interface that refers to your type (`MyType`). This obviously cannot be done without the implementation referring to your type. This is the only thing that prevents the above code from working.

If you get rid of the `MyType`:

```
type TypeGetter interface {
    GetType() interface {
        Title() string
        Price() int
    }
}
```

And the implementation:

```
func (g CustomTypeGetter) GetType() interface {
    Title() string
    Price() int
} {
    return CustomType{"Hello", 42}
}
```

Then this code will work:

```
func main() {
    tg := external.CustomTypeGetter{}
    mypackage.MyHandler(tg)
}
```

Yes, this requires repetition, but only because you don't want an unknown / future implementation to refer to *your* type (to not depend on it).

In this case you may change `MyHandler()` to take a value of type `MyType` (get rid of the "factory"):

```
func MyHandler(t MyType) {
    fmt.Printf("Title: %s, Price: %d", t.Title(), t.Price())
}
```

And any value that implements `MyType` may be passed. Add a "factory" to the `external` package:

```
func NewCustomType(title string, price int) CustomType {
    return CustomType{
        title: title,
        price: price,
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
func main() {
    t := external.NewCustomType("title", 1)
    mypackage.MyHandler(t)
}
```

If you truly require the factory pattern, then yes, creating a 3rd package that will hold `MyType` is the way to go. Then both your app and the implementations may refer to this 3rd package.

Comment: Yes, changing `GetType()` to return `interface{}` instead of `MyType` would work, but then I will lose the compiler type check, and need to do type assertion; which I'd prefer not to.

Comment: @user1102018 No, this solution is type safe. I didn't use the empty interface but an anonymous interface with the required methods! No type assertion is needed as the working example proves (there is no type assertion in the example).